# SharePoint 2013 Custom Edit Form Sorry This site hasn't been shared with you

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, edit-form

I have a Document Library that has a custom edit form for properties. When I try to edit them I receive the "

> Sorry this site hasn't been shared with you" page.

The Edit Form is opening as a page.

I receive **HTTP 302 error** when the site is trying to get:

```
 /Forms/myEditForm.aspx and 
 /_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId
```

Has any of you had this behavior?

The funny thing is that it worked for months before and now suddenly I've got this error.

Thanks